# Is a vector field irrotational iff its Jacobian is symmetric?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth vector field.  I conjecture that $F$ is irrotational iff its Jacobian is a symmetric matrix.

In two and three dimensions, this seems clear from Green and Stokes theorem.  I conjecture this is true for any $n$ dimensions.

Is this true? If so, it raises a few additional questions:

1. We normally use curl to describe a vector field.  Can we use curl, or at least its magnitude, to describe matrices? That is, can we use the magnitude of curl to measure how much a matrix rotates, or how non symmetric it is? Can we use the components of curl to tell us the nature of this asymmetry / rotation?
2. Would it be correct to say that for any two distinct dimensions $i, j$, that the measure of asymmetry $A_{ij} - A_{ji}$ is a measure of how much the matrix rotates a vector in the $i,j$ plane?
3. There are many well known types of matrices with interesting properties (e.g. orthogonal).  If the Jacobian of $F$ is an "interesting" matrix, what does it tell us about $F$? For example, if $J(F)$ is orthogonal?

Comment: How do you define irrotational in dimension $\geq 4$? (One option is to consider the canonical differential operator $\alpha$ that takes vector fields on $\Bbb R^n$ to *bivector* fields on $\Bbb R^n$ and declare a vector field $X$ to be *irrotational* if $\alpha(X) = 0$. In the case of $3$ dimensions, the Hodge star operation identifies bivector fields with vector fields, and making that identification thus gives a differential operator that takes vector fields to vector fields, namely the usual curl.)

Comment: @TravisWillse I'd define as follows: $F$ is irrotational if for every plane $P$, for any orthogonal unit vectors $a, b$ in $P$, then $Fa \cdot b = F b  \cdot a$.  Does that definition work?

Comment: Does $Fa$ here mean the directional derivative of $F$ with respect to $a$? If so, I think definition is equivalent to the one in my comment, and also that your conjecture is true. (It doesn't seem the plane $P$ plays any role in the definition, since orthogonal unit vectors always span a plane anyway.)

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks.  Here's an improved definition, then: $F$ is irrotational if for all points $v$, for all orthogonal unit vectors $a,b$, then $J[F|v]a \cdot b = J[F|v]b \cdot a$.  Is that correct?

Comment: If I understand the notation, then yes.

Comment: Regarding (2), the antisymmetrization map $A \mapsto A - A^\top$ is (up to an overall scale) the orthogonal projection with respect to a natural inner product onto the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n, \Bbb R)$ of infinitesimal rotations. In that sense, $A - A^\top$ is exactly a measure of how much $A$ infinitesimally rotates vectors. Specializing to the $x_i x_j$-planes, resp., the $ij$-entries, gives basically your characterization.

Comment: @TravisWillse What Is "infinitesimal" about the rotation? It certainly has a macroscopic effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the question here is to make sense of what *irrotational* means in $\Bbb R^n$ for $n \geq 4$. One way to approach a definition is as follows.

Recall that a smooth vector field ${\bf X} = (P, Q, R)$ with domain $\Bbb R^3$ is irrotational, i.e., has curl ${\bf 0}$, if and only if it is conservative, that is, if and only if $${\bf X} = \operatorname{grad} \varphi$$ for some (smooth) function $\varphi : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$,
equivalently,
$$\varphi_x = P, \qquad \varphi_y = Q, \qquad \varphi_z = R .$$
Indeed, since $\varphi$ is smooth, Clairaut's Theorem implies that the components $P, Q, R$ of $\bf X$ satistfy the differential condition $$Q_x = \varphi_{yx} = \varphi_{xy} = P_y$$
and its analogues for other pairs of independent variables, $P_z = R_x$ and $R_y = Q_z$. But if these $3$ conditions hold, then
$$\operatorname{curl} {\bf X} = (R_y - Q_z, P_z - R_x, Q_x - P_y) = {\bf 0} .$$

In this case, the Jacobian of $\bf X$, regarded as a map $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ is simply the (automatically symmetric) Hessian of the potential function $\varphi$:
$$\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}) = \pmatrix{
P_x & P_y & P_z \\
Q_x & Q_y & Q_z \\
R_x & R_y & R_z
}
=
\pmatrix{
\varphi_{xx} & \varphi_{xy} & \varphi_{xz} \\
\varphi_{xy} & \varphi_{yy} & \varphi_{yz} \\
\varphi_{xz} & \varphi_{yz} & \varphi_{zz}}$$

In $n$ dimensions the situation is essentially the same: If a vector field ${\bf X} = (X^1, \ldots, X^n)$ with domain $\Bbb R^n$ is conservative, say, with potential $\varphi$, then for all indices $i, j$ we have
$$\partial_{x_j} X^i = \partial_{x_j} \partial_{x_i} \phi = \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j} \phi = \partial_{x_i} X^j,$$
a total of $\frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)$ nontrivial conditions. So it's natural to define the $n$-dimensional analogue of curl to be a map $\alpha$ that takes a vector field $\bf X$ to to the collection $\partial_{x_i} X^j - \partial_{x^j} X^i$ of functions, where $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, and we can declare ${\bf X}$ to be **irrotational** if $\alpha({\bf X}) = (0, \ldots, 0)$.  Again it turns out that vanishing of $\alpha({\bf X})$ is not only necessary but also sufficient to guarantee that ${\bf X}$ is a gradient. As in the $3$-dimensional case, the conditions $\partial_{x_i} X^j = \partial_{x_j} X^i$ are exactly that the Jacobian $\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X})$ of $\bf X$ (at each point) is symmetric (hence equal to the Hessian of the potential), giving the desired equivalence of conditions:
$$\boxed{\textrm{$\bf X$ is irrotational} \Leftrightarrow \textrm{$\operatorname{Jac}({\bf X})$ is symmetric}} .$$

There are two more systematic ways to organize the above construction:

(1) Regard $\alpha$ as the map taking a vector field ${\bf X}$ to the skew-symmetrization of its Jacobian:
$$\operatorname{Alt} \operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}) = \frac12 [\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}) - (\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}))^\top].$$ This viewpoint makes the desired equivalence of conditions more or less immediate.

(2) Regard the map $\alpha$ as taking a vector field ${\bf X} = \sum_i X^i {\bf e}_i$ to the *[bivector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector)*,
$$\alpha({\bf X}) := \sum_{i < j} (\partial_{x_i} X^j - \partial_{x^j} X_i) \, {\bf e}_i \wedge {\bf e}_j .$$ From this point of view $\alpha$ fits into a natural sequence of operators that can be identified with the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) on Euclidean space.

**Example** In dimension $3$, there is a canonical identification between vectors and bivectors on $\Bbb R^3$, namely,
$$
{\bf i} \leftrightarrow {\bf j} \wedge {\bf k}, \qquad
{\bf j} \leftrightarrow {\bf k} \wedge {\bf i}, \qquad
{\bf k} \leftrightarrow {\bf i} \wedge {\bf j} ,
$$
and under this identification we can think of $\alpha$ as a map that takes vector fields to vector fields, and this map is exactly the usual curl. Also using a similar identification for $\operatorname{div}$ lets us regard the sequence of operators mentioned in (2) with the usual sequence $\operatorname{grad}, \operatorname{curl}, \operatorname{div}$ on $\Bbb R^3$.

**Jacobians satisfying matrix conditions**

It turns out that the symmetric part $$\operatorname{Sym} \operatorname{Jac} {\bf X} = \frac12 [\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}) + (\operatorname{Jac} ({\bf X}))^\top]$$ of the Jacobian of ${\bf X}$ measures exactly how the metric structure of $\Bbb R^n$ distorts infinitesimally when we let points "flow" along ${\bf X}$ (more precisely, we can identify that symmetric part with the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) $\mathcal{L}_{\bf X} \bar g$ of the flat metric $\bar g$ on $\Bbb R^n$ by $\bf X$.) So, a vector field whose Jacobian (at every point) has zero symmetric part---equivalently, whose Jacobian is skew-symmetric---is exactly one under whose flow the metric structure is preserved. Such vector fields are called [Killing (vector) fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field).

Similarly, the trace $\operatorname{tr} \operatorname{Jac} {\bf X}$ of the Jacobian of ${\bf X}$ measures how volume distorts infinitesimally when we let points flow "along" ${\bf X}$, and so a vector field that has tracefree Jacobian (at each point) is exactly one under which volume is preserved.

**Remark** In the above presentation I specifically treated the case that the domain of the vector field is all of $\Bbb R^n$. If that's not the case, most of the above still holds with one important exception: It's still always true that if $\bf X$ is conservative then it satisfies $\alpha(\bf X) = {\bf 0}$ (in dimension $3$, $\operatorname{curl} {\bf X} = {\bf 0}$), but the converse need only hold when the domain of $\bf X$ is simply connected, or, roughly speaking, has no "holes" of a certain type. This observation can be turned around to use $\alpha$ to *detect* holes in a set and is the beginning of [de Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology).

Comment: Great answer, both the content and exposition (succinct, vigorous, and yet quite clear). "For a vector field... requiring that $X$ is conservative imposes conditions $\partial_{x_i} X^j = \partial_{x_j} X^i$".  I don't see where you proved this.  While I agree this is true, it seems to me that this can't just be assumed, as it's an essential part of the claim we are trying to prove.

Comment: Regarding the conditions in n dimensions, the argument is essentially the same as it is in 3 dimensions: If ${\bf X} = \operatorname{grad} \varphi$, then Clairaut's Theorem gives $$\partial_{x_j} X^i = \partial_{x_j} \partial_{x_i} \phi = \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j} \phi = \partial_{x_i} X^j .$$ I've made this fact more explicit in the answer.

Comment: Regarding "infinitesimal": Recall that a velocity vector can represent an infinitesimal change---for example, given a smooth vector parametrization ${\bf r}(t)$, for any time $t = a$ and small $\epsilon$ we have that ${\bf r}(a + \epsilon) \approx {\bf r}(a) + \epsilon {\bf r}'(a)$. (More precisely the difference of the two sides is $O(\epsilon^2)$.)

Comment: Similarly, we can think of a vector field as an infinitesimal change at each point in its domain. Moving "along" the vector field takes each point ${\bf x} \in \Bbb R^n$, respectively, approximately to $T_\epsilon({\bf x}) := {\bf x} + \epsilon {\bf X}$. Depending on ${\bf X}$, a region $D$ could be mapped under this transformation to a region whose volume is greater than, equal to, or less than that of $D$. The infinitesimal change of volume of $D$ is $\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right\vert_0 (\textrm{volume of $T_{\epsilon}(D)$})$.

Comment: Relatedly, a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ does not preserve distances, but $I + \epsilon A$ preserves distances to first order: $$(I + \epsilon A)^\top (I + \epsilon A) - I \in O(\epsilon^2)$$.

Answer (score 4):

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth vector field. I conjecture that  is irrotational iff its Jacobian is a symmetric matrix. [...] I conjecture this is true for any  dimensions. Is this true?

To answer you question, we have to extend the concept of a vector field being irrotational (curl-free) to higher dimensions. This requires a more generalized form of curl that fits into the context of **differential forms** and **exterior derivatives**. The notion of a symmetric Jacobian implies that the mixed partial derivatives of the vector field components are equal (Schwarz's theorem), which aligns with the field being irrotational in a generalised sense. Let’s look a this in more detail.

In the language of differential forms, a vector field $F$ being irrotational in $\mathbb{R}^n$ means that its associated differential 1-form $\omega$ has a vanishing exterior derivative, i.e., $d\omega = 0$. In other words, the irrotational vector fields correspond to the closed 1-forms Note that d^2 = 0 implies that any exact form is closed, so any conservative vector field is irrotational. **Conversely, we then have that closed 1-forms are exact if U is simply connected.**

The 1-form $\omega$ is related to $F$ through a musical isomorphism (\flat or \sharp) between the tangent and cotangent bundles, typically depending on the metric of the space, e.g. the Riemannian metric.

Let $F = (F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_n)$. The associated differential 1-form $\omega$ is given by

$$\omega = F_1 dx_1 + F_2 dx_2 + \ldots + F_n dx_n$$

The exterior derivative $d\omega$ of this 1-form in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ is a 2-form, given by

$$ d\omega = \sum_{i < j} \left(\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}\right) dx_i \wedge dx_j$$

For F to be irrotational ($d\omega = 0)$, each coefficient in this sum must vanish, meaning we must have

$$\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} \quad \forall i, j $$

Great!

**Now this directly translates to the symmetry of the Jacobian matrix of $F$, where each off-diagonal element $\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i}$ is equal to its transpose counterpart $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}$.** Hopefully this answers any doubts you had with the formulation of your conjecture to higher dimensions.

> We normally use curl to describe a vector field. Can we use curl, or at least its magnitude, to describe matrices? That is, can we use the magnitude of curl to measure how much a matrix rotates, or how non symmetric it is? Can we use the components of curl to tell us the nature of this asymmetry / rotation?

Traditionally, curl is a vector operation defined for vector fields, not matrices. Though I guess the idea behind curl (measuring local rotation) can be conceptually extended to matrices. Say you have a matrix representing a linear transformation, while you can't directly apply the curl operation, you can interpret the antisymmetric part of a matrix as an indicator of rotational properties, where the antisymmetric part is given by $J-J^\text{T}$. You could think of the magnitude of this antisymmetric part as an analogue to the magnitude of curl for a vector field, indicating the degree of rotation/asymmetry? Not too sure what you’re asking here.

> Would it be correct to say that for any two distinct dimensions i,j, that the measure of asymmetry $A_\text{ij}−A_\text{ji}$ is a measure of how much the matrix rotates a vector in the i,j plane?

Indeed, the elements $A_\text{ij}−A_\text{ji}$ represent the antisymmetric part of the Jacobian matrix. In the language of differential forms, these components correspond to the coefficients of the exterior derivative of the associated 1-form of the vector field. More specifically, they appear in the 2-form obtained by taking the exterior derivative, reflecting the *twisting* or *rotational* properties of the vector field in higher dimensions.

> There are many well known types of matrices with interesting properties (e.g. orthogonal). If the Jacobian of F is an "interesting" matrix, what does it tell us about F? For example, if $J(F)$ is orthogonal?

If J(F) is orthogonal, it means that the linear approximation of
F at each point preserves lengths and angles. In physical terms, this implies that the transformation F locally behaves like a rotation/reflection. Also, orthogonal transformations are isometries, meaning that F preserves the Euclidean structure of the space.

For more examples of so-called *interesting* matrices:

- **Symmetric Jacobian** $\rightarrow$ F resembles a scaling transformation locally, stretching or compressing along orthogonal axes.
- **Skew-Symmetric Jacobian** $\rightarrow$ F is locally “pure” rotation (e.g.: in 3 dimensions, a skew-symmetric matrix can be associated with an angular velocity vector).
- **Diagonal Jacobian** $\rightarrow$ F acts independently on each coordinate axis, scaling each axis separately.

Comment: Thanks! You write on one point "...the degree of rotation/asymmetry? Not too sure what you’re asking here."  I decided this needed to be its own question, which I wrote here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814920/what-is-the-change-in-angle-of-of-a-symmetric-matrix-when-summed-over-a-plane

Comment: "If J(F) is orthogonal, it means that the linear approximation of F at each point preserves lengths and angles. In physical terms, this implies that the transformation F locally behaves like a rotation/reflection."  It would seem to me that this is misleading or perhaps incorrect.  Rather, it implies that that the linear approximation preserves  **differences in** lengths and angles (in the region around each point), and that $F$ locally rotates or reflects the **differences** between them.  Am I correct? Or can you please explain further?