# What is the change in angle of of a symmetric matrix when summed over a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, intuition, conjectures

A symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors with real eigenvalues, and hence can be thought of as scaling along a particular orthogonal set of axes.

Of course, not all vectors are (usually) eigenvectors, and therefore many individual vectors will have their direction changed under a symmetric matrix.

It seems to me, however, that these direction changes will somehow "cancel out" in the sense that there is no net rotation by a symmetric matrix.  I don't know how to state this more precisely, other than to observe that $A_{ij} - A_{ji}$ is a measure of the rotation in the $i,j$ plane (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814410/is-a-vector-field-irrotational-iff-its-jacobian-is-symmetric/4814510#4814510)).

That is, if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, for any plane $P$, the net direction change of $Av$ over all vectors $v \in P$ is zero.  Again, I'm not sure how state this more precisely, but perhaps it could be formulated as an integral.

Is my intuition correct? And how can it be stated more precisely?

Comment: What is the 'net direction change of $Av$" ? Is it $Av - v$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis Defining that properly is the heart of my question.  I can say the following: In $\mathbb R^3$, two vectors $v,w$ define a normal $n = v \times w$ and angle of rotation $\phi$.  Is there some type of "conservation" or other invariant of $n, \phi$ across all $x, Ax$ when $A$ is symmetric? This is clearly a imprecisely specified, not yet well defined question - that's exactly where I need help.  And, if so, does this generalize to $\mathbb R^n$?